# Need to merge the Map and List with the same dates

Tags: scala

I have a Map where key = LocalDateTime and value = Group

```
def someGroup(/.../): List[Group] = {
    someCode.map {
    /.../
    }.map(group => (group.completedDt, group)).toMap
    /.../
}
```

And there is also List [Group], where Group (completedDt: LocalDateTime, cost: Int), in which always cost = 0

An example of what I have:

map: `[(2021-04-01T00:00:00.000, 500), (2021-04-03T00:00:00.000, 1000), (2021-04-05T00:00:00.000, 750)]`

list: `((2021-04-01T00:00:00.000, 0),(2021-04-02T00:00:00.000, 0),(2021-04-03T00:00:00.000, 0),(2021-04-04T00:00:00.000, 0),(2021-04-05T00:00:00.000, 0))`

The expected result is:
list `((2021-04-01T00:00:00.000, 500),(2021-04-02T00:00:00.000, 0),(2021-04-03T00:00:00.000, 1000),(2021-04-04T00:00:00.000, 0),(2021-04-05T00:00:00.000, 750))`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that if there's a time appearing in both that you want to combine the costs:

```
type Group = (LocalDateTime, Int)  // completedDt, cost
val groupMap: Map[LocalDateTime, Group] = ???
val groupList: List[Group] = ???

val combined = 
  groupList.foldLeft(groupMap) { (acc, group) =>
    val completedDt = group._1
    
    if (acc.contains(completedDt)) {
      val nv = completedDt -> (acc(completedDt)._2 + group._2)
      acc.updated(completedDt, nv)
    } else acc + (completedDt -> group)
  }.values.toList.sortBy(_._1)  // You might need to define an Ordering[LocalDateTime]
```

The notation in your question leads me to think `Group` is just a pair, not a `case class`.  It's also worth noting that I'm not sure what having the map be `Map[LocalDateTime, Group]` vs. `Map[LocalDateTime, Int]` (and thus by definition a collection of `Group`) buys you.

EDIT: if you have a general collection of collections of `Group`, you can

```
val groupLists: List[List[Group]] = ???

groupList.foldLeft(Map.empty[LocalDateTime, Group]) { (acc, lst) =>
  lst.foldLeft(acc) { (m, group) =>
    val completedDt = group._1

    if (m.contains(completedDt)) {
      val nv = completedDt -> (acc(completedDt)._2 + group._2)
      m.updated(completedDt, nv)
    } else m + (completedDt -> group)
  }
}.values.toList.sortBy(_._2)
```

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for your reply!
What if we have two List, and not a Map with a List?